# How could I get alchemist to always open its test report in a window at the bottom?

Tags: window-splitting

alchemist.el has functions for running tests. These functions use `display_buffer` to show test results. Is there a way to ensure that all Alchemist test results open in a window that is the bottom-most window? In other words, if I have two windows, split vertically, one is the test file, when I run the test, it should create a 3rd window beneath the two that are split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [popwin.el](https://github.com/m2ym/popwin-el) or [shackle.el](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle) emacs package or the emacs native display-buffer https://gist.github.com/tonini/0d3f9433b214044a870e

```el
;; Display alchemist buffers always at the right side
;; Just change (side . right) with the position you would like 'bottom, 'top, 'right or 'left
;; Source: http://www.lunaryorn.com/2015/04/29/the-power-of-display-buffer-alist.html
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             `(,(rx bos (or "*alchemist test report*"
                            "*alchemist mix*"
                            "*alchemist help*"))
                    (display-buffer-reuse-window
                     display-buffer-in-side-window)
               (reusable-frames . visible)
               (side            . right)
               (window-width   . 0.5)))
```

If you need additional help call me on the #emacs-elixir channel on freenode irc. (Nick: tonini)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with popwin:

```el
(push '("*alchemist test report*" :position bottom :noselect t)
    popwin:special-display-config)
(push '("*alchemist mix*" :position bottom :noselect t)
    popwin:special-display-config)
(push '("*alchemist help*" :position bottom :noselect t)
    popwin:special-display-config)
```